# ConstraintLayout View with 0dp height has a different actual height when using math_parent and 0dp as width

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

This problem is better described with an example:

[image]

As you can see in the resulting rendered layout, the heights from `first_view` and `second_view` are different, and the only thing that is different is that the `first_view` uses

- `layout_width=match_parent`

instead of

- `layout_width="0dp"`;
- `layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"`;
- `layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"`.

---

**Is it a bug or the expected behavior?**

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout):

> Important: MATCH_PARENT is not recommended for widgets contained in a
>   ConstraintLayout. Similar behavior can be defined by using
>   MATCH_CONSTRAINT with the corresponding left/right or top/bottom
>   constraints being set to "parent".

and [official training](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)

> Note: You cannot use match_parent for any view in a ConstraintLayout.
>   Instead use "match constraints" (0dp).

That being said, your example is also not valid because you are using `0dp` (match constraints) for height without specifying the bottom constraint which might lead to unexpected behaviour of the view. To match constraints for a dimension you need to declare both ends.